# Subtracting a value from list of lists

Tags: r, list, nested

```
c_k <- c(2, 4, 10, 50, 100, 500, 10000, 100000)
c_flips <- lapply(c_k, function(n) replicate(1000, sum((sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE)))))
d_fk <- c_k/2
d_flips <- lapply(seq_along(d_fk), function(i) lapply(c_flips[i], function(v) v - d_fk[i])[1])
```

In the above code, I'm trying to subtract from every element in `c_flips` the corresponding value from `d_fk`. I've tried using mapply, several different lapply's, but I never seem to end up with the same datatype as `c_flips`.

I want `d_flips` to be a list of vectors like `c_flips`, but instead I'm getting a list of lists of length 1 with the vectors as the only element in the lists.

Can an R pro help me out?

Comment: Do you just mean `d_flips <- lapply(seq_along(d_fk), function(i) c_flips[[i]] - d_fk[i])`? It sounds/looks like you're nesting too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully i understood you correctly. Using

```
d_flips<-mapply('-',c_flips,d_fk,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

the `str` of the result looks like this:

```
List of 8
 $ : num [1:1000] 1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 -1 ...
 $ : num [1:1000] 0 -1 0 -1 -1 1 0 0 -2 0 ...
 $ : num [1:1000] -1 0 -3 1 -2 0 1 1 0 -3 ...
 $ : num [1:1000] 1 1 0 9 -2 6 -4 -3 5 5 ...
 $ : num [1:1000] 2 3 0 0 2 -14 -9 -7 -1 8 ...
 $ : num [1:1000] -24 10 -4 1 -15 1 5 7 0 -4 ...
 $ : num [1:1000] -27 -5 5 82 68 -9 53 -154 31 -74 ...
 $ : num [1:1000] -96 193 -171 11 -186 216 79 24 -114 -25 ...
```